# python virtualenvs conflict with kinetic

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set up a virtualenvs for python 3.1 with opencv3. But when I am in the virtual env and execute python import cv2.  Apparently you have to create a link of the 3.1.so file to cv2.so .  I get an error relating to cv2 /opt/ros/kinetic . I do not know why it is looking here? If I uninstall ros then it works fine, no error. Any thoughts.
Update: if I remove the .bashrc source kinetic setup then it also works fine in the virt. What ever the setup is doing is causing a conflict  even when the ros is set up outside the virtual env.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261011/python-virtualenvs--conflict-with-kinetic/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-05-03**:
Try this: reinstall opencv3 while in the virtualenvs and specify the target install path to your virtualenvs opencv3 desired directory using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PPREFIX=/your/desired/venv/directory`

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-05-04**:
Thanks....I will keep this i mind for future reference. Right now I can use both enviroments by just  commenting on/off the source lines in the .bashrc file.

**Comment by [Daniel Tobon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31563/daniel-tobon/) on 2017-08-12**:
what line in .bashrc file?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-08-12**:
if false; then
workon cvp3
export OPENCV_VERSION=3
else
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [waschbaer00](https://answers.ros.org/users/34002/waschbaer00/) on 2018-03-07**:
I am quite curious on this question, could you share more you know, give more instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now I can use both environments by just commenting on/off the source lines in the .bashrc file. I am closing this a good enough work around solution.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waschbaer00](https://answers.ros.org/users/34002/waschbaer00/) on 2018-03-07**:
However if you comment on or off everytime, this means you can not run ROS and your program depend on vitual env simutanously, right?

**Comment by [waschbaer00](https://answers.ros.org/users/34002/waschbaer00/) on 2018-03-07**:
BTW, if the python is global(which is not your case, but maybe could inspire you)
you don't need to comment on or off, try to add  export $PYTHONPATH with your global python path in ~/.bashrc, as the same time, keep the source line for ros. Then open new terminal, python3, import cv2. It works for m

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2018-06-24**:
Thanks for your suggestion ... I no longer have this set up but will keep this solution in mind if I run across this again.